# Apache Drill query HBase table

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-drill

I am using drill-embedded to execute SQL, I can see the tables in HBase. Here is the terminal output..

[image]
But, I'm not able to perform query on them, it is the raising the following error:

```
 0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> SELECT * FROM students;


Error: SYSTEM ERROR: IllegalAccessError: tried to access method
com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator

[Error Id: 9c656263-c774-4aaf-a789-d4e374adb69b on localhost:31010]
(state=,code=0)
```

Please let me know what I have to do to perform a query on Drill, thanks in advance.

Comment: can you run this and see what it gives: select count(*) from hbase.\`students\`;

Comment: thanks @SrihariKaranth, the student table contains 4 records, i just tried it with drill 1.6 and it working fine, as some blogs suggested that there are some problem with the dependency.

Comment: now my configurations are hadoop 2.7, hbase 1.2.4 and drill 1.6... there may be some issue with drill 1.8 with the same hbase and hadoop configuration... however I'll run the query you suggested and let you know...

Answer (score 1):

#### This issue is  more related to Hbase.

`com.google.common.base.Stopwatch` class is present in guava jar.

The constructors are changed to package private at version 17 or 18.

Default constructor of `Stopwatch` class became `private` since Guava v.17 and marked deprecated even earlier.

seems like you are using latest version of guava, you could lower the version and try again which has suitable constructor.

If you are using maven/gradle you have to adjust dependencies that to fit aforementioned way.

Please have a look at this issue [HBASE-14126](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-14126) which was clearly explained

Comment: dear Ram, I'm a new user and and that was my first question/post, so i cant acknowledge it at that time, it's not allowed (as my reputation is less then 15 at that time), now you can see the change... and thanks again for your response...

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Replace Guava 18 jar with Guava 16 jar in apache-drill-1.9.0/jars/3rdparty folder. You can find Guava 16 jar here:

https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release16

Source: https://blogs.perficient.com/delivery/blog/2017/05/15/how-to-configure-tableau-and-drill-to-show-data-from-hbase-hive/